# Xcode add too many pictures

Tags: xcode, assets, photos

There are 1500 pics, each 64x64 pixels, that I need to use within my Xcode Project.  I will use these pictures in the TableView, but Xcode crashes when I put it directly into the Assets.xcassets directory. What is the best way to use these pictures?

Comment: did you try to add them in batches and not all together?

Comment: When you say 1500 pictures, does this include @ 1x, @ 2x, and @ 3x icon sizes?

Comment: it only has 1x size

Comment: xcode crashes while trying to throw away all

Answer (score 1):

Adding your images into the Xcode project - either in an asset catalog, or directly as an images subdirectory - will pollute interface builder - fill up every combo box where you could choose images, e.g. as a background image (normally, "pollute" would normaly not include "crash", but we all know Xcode all too well...)

If I understand you correctly, you only want use those images "per index", or at least only programatically, like in your table view. But you do not want to manually assign them in Xcode Interface builder.

I would suggest to

- create a container file (like .zip, without compression) with all your images
- add the .zip to your project
- at program startup, uncompress the .zip file into the cache directory of your app (first check if you already did this the program start before :-)
- access the image files via the path to the cache directory

If the image files are too large (so your application footprint on the device would get too high), just don't decompress them and take them directly from the .zip archive

There are several (sample) projects available to use .zip in Swift, like https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip

Comment: do {
            let filePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Logo", withExtension: "zip")!
            let unzipDirectory = try Zip.quickUnzipFile(filePath) // Unzip
            
            
            let url = String(describing: unzipDirectory) + "1.png"
            print(url)
            let logoUrl = URL(string: url)
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: logoUrl!) 
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.img.image = UIImage(data: data!) 
                }
            }
        }

Comment: self.img.image = UIImage(data: data!), 
this picture does not show

Comment: Maybe you should add your code to your question, just for formatting reasons. If the image does not show up, you should investigate the contents of `data` in the debugger, e.g. if it really is a .png image (check magic header, see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics )

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest another alternative to zip method. In this method, Xcode does not know anything about the files, so it cannot crash or freeze trying to index them. Also this method does not have overhead of zip method.

- Place your assets to your project form finder. Such as './assets'.
- Create a new run script phase on Build Phases
- Paste this script

```
SOURCE="$SRCROOT/assets"
TARGET="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app"
rsync -r --delete "$SOURCE" "$TARGET"
```

- Use the images with `UIImage(named: "assets/filename.png")`